# How do I pass the return value of a bean to an XML attribute using Spring Integration? Most likely involves SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I'm following the [Spring Integration quick start tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/#scratch) and everything is working fine as outlined.  I see that in the transformer a `@newline` `Bean` is referenced...

```
<int:transformer
    input-channel="tweets"
    expression="payload.fromUser + ' : ' + payload.text + @newline"
    output-channel="files"/>
```

.

```
@Bean
public String newline(){
    return System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

In the twitter `search-inbound-channel-adapter` the query attribute is set to `#HelloWorld`.  I want it to be set dynamically based on the return value of a `Bean`.  Following similar convention as was done in the transformer, I tried to set the twitter adapter to the following:

```
<twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="tweets"
    query="@query"
    twitter-template="twitterTemplate">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"></int:poller>
</twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

and then create a `Bean` to grab the query value as defined in an environment variable passed in when the application is executed...

```
@Bean
public String query(Environment env){
    return env.getProperty("query");
}
```

Everything gets set properly but the twitter search expression is literally `@query` instead of the return value from the `Bean` annotated method.

Two questions...
1. Why is `@newline` parsed as a `Bean` reference but `@query` is not?
2. What do I need to do in order to achieve this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
<int:transformer
    input-channel="tweets"
    expression="payload.fromUser + ' : ' + payload.text + @newline"
    output-channel="files"/>
```

in literal meaning ,this attributte **expression** meaning that value is an expression, but as follow is not ,so you shoud use spEL.

```
<twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="tweets"
    query="#{@query}"
    twitter-template="twitterTemplate">
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching on Spring Expression Language, here is the solution.

```
<twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="tweets"
    query="#{@query}"
    twitter-template="twitterTemplate">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"></int:poller>
</twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter>
```